# Angular: ngx-responsive hides elements even when conditions are met

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using [this](https://github.com/ManuCutillas/ngx-responsive) library for implementing different designs on desktop and mobile on an Angular app (v4.2.4). I used ng2-responsive instead of ngx-responsive as stated in the docs. When I set the responsive directive on an element, it doesn't show up at all even when the set conditions are met.

My current implementation looks like this:

```
<div class="desktop" *responsive="{sizes:{min: 768}}">...</div>
<div class="mobile" *responsive="{sizes:{max: 767}}">...</div>
```

and I am importing this module in a submodule of another submodule of AppModule.

It doesn't seem to work even if I change the conditions. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

add the ResponsiveModule with the forRoot call in the  AppModule.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    ResponsiveModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```